# Performance of CPU with two caches

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-cache, memory-access

I was very confused how to solve the problem when there are two levels of cache, My doubt is how does we quantify the performance when there are two caches. Consider a problem like this

Cache L1 access time of main memory = T1 and miss rate = X%.

Cache L2 access time of main memory = T2 and miss rate = Y%.

CPI of processor without memory stalls is C. and clock rate is fGHz.

How much faster the performance be after adding L2 cache?

Comment: There is a blatant problem here: L1 cache would be faster and smaller than L2 cache, and L1 cache misses are often filled from L2 cache, not main memory.

Comment: If we approximate that all the miss rates are independent, we can calculate the average memory access time with and without the L2 cache. Hint: Misses in the L1 cache go to the L2 cache, which can hit or miss.